# Allow users to view all processes

Tags: windows-server-2003, task-manager

I want to allow accounts with only user permissions on a Windows Server 2003 machine to be able to view all processes.  I simply want them to be able to open task manager and be able to check the box that says "Show processes from all users".  How can I enable that?

Answer (score 0):

First option is to use process explorer instead of task manager.